# proof of key/value membership on a JSON

Tags: cryptography, circom, cairo-lang

Is there a way to create zk proof that a particular key and value are present on a JSON without giving information about that key/value?

For example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "john",
        "balance": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "peter",
        "balance": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "balance": "6"
    },
    {
        "name": "bob",
        "balance": "4"
    }
]
```

I want to prove that the JSON contains an entry with a key `name` and value `john` without giving away that information.

I have checked different zk frameworks but only seen merkle tree proof of membership given some leaves.